# What would cause a project to suddenly lose track of one of its references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, opennetcf, assembly-references

I successfully complile my project, closed it, ran 7-zip on it, then opened it back up to find, on attempting to build it, three err msgs of the sort:

> - The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the class or namespace 'OpenNETCF' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> - The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the class or namespace 'OpenNETCF' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> - The type or namespace name 'IO' does not exist in the class or namespace 'OpenNETCF' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

OpenNETCF is still in my References list, so...???

I removed OpenNETCF.dll, then added it back and rebuilt, but that didn't help.

Comment: Were they perhaps relative references to files outside the region you zipped, i.e. `../../../somepath/lib/some.dll` ? then if you unzip to a different location, the refs will no longer resolve...

Comment: But when I removed it and then added it back, that didn't solve it...

Comment: I swear, if I didn't have a bad memory, I'd have no memory at all. One of the related posts was my own from two months back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719612/why-would-i-get-the-type-of-namespace-name-bla-does-not-exist-after-no-ch?rq=1
And again, shutting down the XP Mode virtual machine and restarting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the [Teklynx LabelView](http://www.teklynx.com/en/products/label-design-solutions/labelview) DLL in use in my application.

To use the DLL, the product must be installed on the PC, and I have to have the DLL in my project so that my code can access it.

My product is installed on my Development PC, also. Occasionally, I will uninstall it after trying a version.

Anytime my product is uninstalled, the LabelView application becomes unregistered on the system. I have set the DLLs as **SharedLegasyFile** and **Permanent** in the VS Deployment project, yet immediately after removing my application, I can try to rebuild my VS2010 project and get undefined item errors.

To fix it, all I have to do is open the LabelView program, close it again, and my VS program will compile with no issues.

I don't know why, but I know it works.

I don't know if ctacke's OpenNETCF package has an interface that you can use to open it so that it can re-register itself, though.